# solve transcendental equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, roots

How to solve a transcendental equation of the type $x^x = a$ with $a>0$, without leaving the solutions expressed in terms of the Lambert $W$ function?

For example the equation

$x^{x}=\left ( \frac{1}{3} \right )^{\frac{1}{4}}$

admit two solutions, how do I get to them by some method

I have applied the usual, but I don't see how to get to the result,
any suggestions, some method, if possible with some steps to get started
Thanks

Comment: If there would be a simpler method in general, nobody would use the Lambert W function.

Comment: Similar methods to express the solution of $x^2=2$ without expressing the solution in terms of the square root function $\sqrt{\cdot}$ can be applied here.

Comment: hi ,But will there be the alternative numerical method? and if so, some indications to implement it please

Comment: If you're asking about numerical methods then you could try Newton's method.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method?wprov=sfla1